# Apply device's font size to an app

Tags: android, android-fonts

Since it is possible to set the font size on an Android device (Settings --> Display --> Font size), is there a way to apply the font size selected to an app by default?

I have seen some apps that succeeded to achieve it but I did not find any information in the Google documentation.

Comment: you mean manipulate the size of all fonts at runtime?

Comment: @Souto yes, based on the device font size

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use ScaleablePixels "sp" units while setting the text size.

Take a look [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp-)

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to automatically update the app's text font size based on the device settings, not set all manually.

Comment: His answer is correct. Using `sp` will follow your design (e.g. title `18sp` and text `14sp`) but at the same time, the physical size on-screen will be bigger or smaller depending on the user preferences. And all of that is done automatically for you, but you still have to build your own design.

Comment: Ok but this does not take into consideration the font size selected in the device settings, my question is based on that, I want the app to reflect what was selected in the settings.

Comment: You are wrong, this is exactly to take into account the user settings, you set a base value with sp that will scale based on the user device settings.

Comment: I just did the test, I set a TextView textsize to 20sp, then I went back to the device settings and changed from "Normal" to "Huge", I then stopped and restarted my app, it did not change anything on the font, the size remained the same in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Nanoc correct answer, if you want to manipulate stuff in Java code is to use the `DisplayMetrics`. Something like that:

```
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

This value is the device screen density scaled as per user "Font Size" settings.

For further info on DisplayMetris and scaledDensity, here is the official docs: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp app detect your device default text size and apply to itself, so yes, it's possible.

> When you want your text to be flexible, based on the user preferences, defne text font sizes using SP (scalable point) units. The Android platform allows dimensional values to be defined in a variety of ways. When it comes to text sizes, you will want to use density-independent units like DP (device-independent pixels) and SP. The SP unit is perfect for text sizes, as it is sensitive to the user's display settings.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-basic-font-sizes--mobile-11194